# iTunes Connect: How do I find out the canonical name of my app?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I want to link to my app using the short http://appstore.com/yangmeyer variant.

While it was easy enough to deduce the canonical name for my app "Trash Cam" (http://appstore.com/trashcam), I haven’t been able to get the canonical name for my most recent app, *[Delighted! – “Nice to meet you!”](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/delighted!-nice-to-meet-you!/id607995866?l=en&mt=8)* (note the exclamation and quotation marks, which are [all part of the app’s name](http://blog.yangmeyer.de/blog/2013/03/11/quotation-marks/) on the App Store).

I read Apple’s [Technical Q&A QA1633](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1633/_index.html), and believe that the canonical name should be "delightednicetomeetyou". But it’s not.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, if you follow the instructions in QA1633 *like a computer would*, you arrive at **delighted–“nicetomeetyou”**. (D’oh.)

And this actually works*) – and even looks prettier**):

http://appstore.com/delighted–“nicetomeetyou”

*) Alas, not in StackOverflow’s Markdown parsing ;-)
**) This is probably my first time that I got actual practical value out of using an en-dash and proper quotation marks!